# grouping archive by year and month using php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I want to create an archive list like this:

- 2014

  - March
  - Feb
  - Jan

    - Post 1
    - Post 2
- 2013

  - November

    - Post 1

I am using by PDO. the table I m using is having postDate as Datetime. postSlug is used to get a clean url. The coding I am using now is:

```
    <h1>Archives</h1>
    <hr />

    <ul>
<?php
$stmt = $db->query("SELECT postTitle, Month(postDate) as Month, Year(postDate) as Year FROM blog_posts_seo ORDER BY postDate DESC");
while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
$posts = $row['postTitle'];
$year = $row['Year'];
    $monthName = date("F", mktime(0, 0, 0, $row['Month'], 10));
    $slug = 'a-'.$row['Month'].'-'.$row['Year'];
        echo "<li>$year</li>";
    echo "<ul><li><a href='$slug'>$monthName</a></li>";

        echo "<ul><li><a href='#'>$posts</a></li></ul></ul>";
}
?>
</ul>
```

The result im getting is as follows:

```
2014
    May
        Post
2013
    June
        Post
2013
    June
        Post
2012
    June
        Post
```

In short how do I group the posts and months accordingly using php?
I am am beginner in php and mysql. Therefore it would be of great help if you can help me in the complete coding if you know the solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about that?

```
$data = array();
while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
  $monthName = date("F", mktime(0, 0, 0, $row['Month'], 10));     
  $data[$row['Year']][$monthName][] = array(
   'post' => $row['postTitle'],
   'slug' => 'a-'.$row['Month'].'-'.$row['Year']
  );
}
echo '<ul>';
foreach ($data as $year => $yearData){
   echo "<li>$year<br/>";
   echo '<ul>';
   foreach ($yearData as $month => $monthData){
      echo "<li>$month<br/>";
      echo '<ul>';
      foreach ($monthData as $number => $postData){
        echo "<li><a href='${postData['slug']}'>Post $number</a><br/>";
        echo "<a href='#'>${postData['post']}</a></li>";
      }
      echo '</ul></li>';
   }
   echo '</ul></li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```

This solution does it the PHP way, but you should be able to get the result with a SQL query too, with something like:

```
SELECT
    Year(postDate) as Year, Month(postDate) as Month,
    GROUP_CONCAT(postTitle) as posts
FROM
    blog_posts_seo
GROUP BY Year, Month
ORDER BY postDate DESC
```

which *should* return all the posts related by year and month in a single row (not tested), separated by commas. Use the `WITH SEPARATOR` option to specify a different separator (check the doc).

Documentation:

- [GROUP BY and GROUP_CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html)