# Chunk Laravel Model results by Month

Tags: laravel

I have a News table, with all a `publish_date` timestamp.

And the result I want is something like:

- July 2015

  - News article
- August 2015

  - News article
  - News article
  - News article
- September 2015

  - News article
  - News article

But how to do that? I tried

```php
public function index()
{
    $articles = App\News::where('publish_date', '>=', Carbon\Carbon::now())->orderBy('publish_date'')->get();
    return view('news.index', compact('articles'));
}
```

In the view I have this ugly thing now:

```php
@foreach($articles as $news)
<h1>{{ $news->title }}</h1>
@if(Carbon::parse($news->publish_date)->month != $m)
<tt>{{ $m = Carbon::parse($news->publish_date)->month }}</tt>
@endif
@endforeach
```

That can be done prettier I hope?

Comment: There are no simple, lean and sexy methods of creating this. What you could do is something as proposed here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23985346/1129489 but don't think this improves what you already got.

Comment: Before you get to the solution, are you sure your code works? there is a syntax error over here "->orderBy('publish_date'') ". There is an extra ' after publish_date